# Simple HVAC solution for an ADU

Tags: hvac

I am looking for a HVAC solution for an ADU that wont break the bank. Talking about providing HVAC for two rooms roughly 250 sq ft and 300 sq ft in size. I live in a region where both the summers and winters are quiet mild.
HVAC contractors have quoted upwards of $10K for ductless multizone mini splits.
I am thinking of portable ACs(both heat/cool) as a solution like the ones below. Do these things work? Are there other solutions?

[https://www.amazon.com/Portable-Conditioner-Dehumidifier-Black-SIlver/dp/B094X3G2SV/ref=sr_1_22_sspa?hvadid=557282111240&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9051977&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=5876836791749693719&hvtargid=kwd-325946514688&hydadcr=28751_14526974&keywords=outdoor+air+conditioner+portable&qid=1696975486&sr=8-22-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9idGY&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B094X3G2SV)

Comment: Where are you located? Code sometimes requires a permanent installed heat system in order to be considered habitable space and to pass  your inspection. If so there are a few other options such as package units which will be cheaper than a mini split, though not as nice.

Comment: @KMJ located in Fremont, CA. I am looking to have something in a window ac range for now,  with a better option later.  So thinking of these indoor ACs that vent outside through window.

Comment: Frankly the portable AC units suck. The PTAC option is probably your lowest dollar version that is easy to DIY. Do check with your inspector, it's possible you can't consider this space that is legal to occupy unless it has permanently installed heat.

Answer (score 4):

Some Mini split systems and all PTAC units can be self installed.

The PTAC units usually only need a 30 amp circuit.  Mini splits for small rooms can be 110V and 20 amp, but to be fair usually require 220 and 40 amp.

If you can follow directions well and can do things like find a stud in a wall and drill a hole you can install Mini splits and PTAC units.

For the Minis you will need an AC gauge set and a vacuum pump. Both can be had without breaking the bank.

I know product recommendation is prohibited, but [here is an example](https://www.sylvane.com/senville-18000-btu-dual-zone-mini-split-heat-pump.html?product_id=114011&s_cid=cse_gpl&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7JOpBhCfARIsAL3bobdLVabI1QxCt0U24DluHnOfLgKDZ5BdsTze6gn4KKvtJmXiIHISJ2AaAkSXEALw_wcB).

And [PTAC](https://www.sylvane.com/friedrich-zoneaire-premier-ptac-electric-heat.html) here.  Again these are just examples and I do not support either.

Comment: PTAC is a pretty solid option here on a cost basis, just make sure you get one with a heat pump not just resistive heating.

Comment: And 240V 40A makes me think that's got to be resistive. I heat 2000 square feet with two minisplits that draw 10.9A maximum (and normally much less.) 240V 15A is plenty for each one.

Comment: Some minis are plug and play set ups that don't need extra tools.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the linked one is resistive for sure, heat pump ones are available though and not even that expensive.

Comment: @crip659 can you please point me to a mini which does not require setup by an hvac technician?

Comment: @FuzzyWuzzy   It will depend on your area and what the local regulations are like, if you can do it yourself or need licensed technicians.  Can do a search for DIY mini splits, but the main question is if your locality will allow you to do the work to install them.

Answer (score 2):

### Portable A/Cs are *not even stupid*

[I won't even speak of the 1-hose models. Even the 2-hose models are not efficient](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc), and your building will certainly not receive its occupancy permit if portable A/C is the only heat source.

If you MUST be "temporary units as permanent HVAC"... then good grief man, build your house friendly to "window A/C units" - I guess some builders save $100/window going with anti-A/C windows like casement types, and their poor tenant must spend $300 extra on a portable unit that's half as efficient. Don't be that jackass.  Build the right windows for window A/Cs (which absolutely do exist as heat pumps), because they are both cheaper and more efficient than portables.  And also take less floor space and don't have ungainly hoses.

They also make "through-the-wall" A/C and heat pump units, however since you're cheap, you should know the units are much more expensive than window units (and window units don't work where a wall unit belongs).

And of course the ultimate "through the wall" unit is the wide rectangular PTAC, seen in cheaper hotels all over the nation.   But they're not cheap. And many of them use resistive heat for heating, on the logic that the hotelier is getting $100/night so who cares.

But we're still in "A/C in a single box" world.

### Split systems are better.

The traditional HVAC industry (Lennox, Carrier, Trane, Bryant,  etc.) is exactly where Detroit was in the late 70s - the key fossil fuel is no longer cheap, nor sourced from friendly countries. Consumers wanted change, and the handwriting was on the wall.  But the American industry denied, manipulated the market and government rather than retool for modern products.  Oil shocks then gave them problems (the Persian Gulf then; Russia now).  HVAC contractors today are like American car dealers then.

You will find prices are reasonable on a forced-air gas furnace and  "That 70's Air Conditioner". The problem is, you very reasonably want a split heat pump system, since that is modern technology.  To resist change, **the domestic manufacturers price that "over the moon"**, hoping to trick you into believing such systems are inherently costly.  Utter faff - just look at any of the bombed out Soviet era apartment buildings from the early Ukraine war. That ain't luxury housing so those occupants are probably under the per-capita GDP of $4000.  Yet every other apartment had a mini-split they say is $11,000. Nonsense.

The $11,000 is the "I don't wanna sell it" price.

So you should be looking at the Asian style systems - they're more efficient anyway.  I'd love for Panasonic or LG to start building a US dealer network that directly competes with the entrenched American dealers.  But some systems are actually designed-for-DIY.  I'm not the biggest MrCool fan as I think their "self-sealing" line-sets won't age well... But several makes have you install normal refrigerant lines, and simply supply the outdoor unit pre-loaded with enough refrigerant for the whole system (assuming line set lengths are reasonable).  You build the line-set, dry-pressurize it with nitrogen to check for leak stability, then evacuate it and open the proper refrigerant valves.  And that's it.

Rather than a dual-head system, I would propose two redundant single-head systems - that way you have an "insurance policy" if one of them goes down.

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to some of these diy for not-the-handy type mini splits? Something doesn’t require one to buy special equipments to install?

Comment: @FuzzyWuzzy the simplest is MrCool. But I'm more impressed with the Pioneer and others that do require a vacuum pump, gage set and nitrogen.

Comment: @FuzzyWuzzy,  I have installed Senville units. You need a vacuum pump and gauge set only to clear out the lines and check that there are no leaks in the connections that you make.  The freon is self contained. You never touch it. It is easy. Just put the parts together. Connect wires that also come with the unit.